# I am learning synchronize() not able to figure out how the code works here

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have created two threads **threadNew** and **incrementer**. And this produces result as **i count=2** and **increment count=2**.

My thought:  It should produce  **i count=1** and **increment count=2**. Could anyone please look into and suggest how to fix ?

```
    public class StaticThreadTest {

    //i = 0 for all instance of this class.
    private static int i = 0;


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //There is no guarantee of thread execution in sequence.
        StaticThreadTest st = new StaticThreadTest();
        StaticThreadTest st1 = new StaticThreadTest();
        st.threadNew.start();
        st1.incrementer.start();

    }

    Thread threadNew = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            synchronized (this) {
                i++;
                System.out.println("i count=" + i);
            }
        }
    });

    Thread incrementer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

        synchronized (this) {
            i++;
            System.out.println("increment count="+i);
        }
    }
});

}
```

Comment: FYI, [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) would probably be a better fit here—but since you're just playing with synchronization that probably doesn't matter. Just wanted to let you know there are other options!

Answer (score 2):

The threads are synchronizing on "this".  But "this" is different for the two threads.  So, in effect, there is no synchronization.  In order for synchronization to work, there must be something in common for all the threads to use to "lock".

Create a static String or Object in StaticThreadTest and synchronize on that.  e.g.

`static final Object SYNC_ON_ME = new Object();`

then, in the later code, use

`synchronized(SYNC_ON_ME) {
...
}`

Comment: Could you please simplify the problem and the solution too ? Thanks.

Comment: @nihar does the edited reply make sense to you?  If so, please "accept" question as answered, if not, please followup with questions.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i is static` here.

static variables don't exist on a per-instance basis, but on a per class basis. 
This means that the same static variable of `i` can be accessed from all instances of class.

Hence it executes it when you start the thread and then again when you call the incrementer.

```
Synchronize would be effective on this object and not the static variable.
```

Comment: Why is the downvote? If downvoted can you please leave a comment too. Tx

Comment: I feel, there are two instances of classes. Each thread would be having two separate copies. But as i is static, the value of i should be reflected to both the threads. If i = i++ i.e, 1 for the first thread for the next thread it would be i++ i.e, 1+1 = 2. threadnew and incrementer are two separate threads too.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda Thanks, I posted the answer quickly and was editing it. I don't mind the downvote if I am wrong, so just a request if downvoted it would be good to leave a comment or something to guide in the right direction. Tx

Comment: @niharm. static variables don't exist on a per-instance basis, but on a per class basis. SO that should solve your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating two completely separate instances of `StaticThreadTest`, which do not share instance fields, nor synchronization when synchronizing on `this`. Your code should work if you make `i` non-static, and replace the main method with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StaticThreadTest st = new StaticThreadTest();
    st.threadNew.start();
    st.incrementer.start();
}
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, that the instances are different matters due to the `synchronized(this)`.

Comment: Thank You Matt. It worked. Can we fix this without removing the **static** keyword from my program ? Thanks.

Comment: -1  IMO, bad form to rely on "this" for synchronization in this example, cause it's not clear to the casual reader if "this" refers to the Runnable, the Thread, or the StaticThreadTest.  Better to be very explicit with threading issues.

Comment: @niharm. sure, but why do you want to?

Answer (score 0):

Your output may be correct. Those threads are not synchronized because you synchronize on different objects.

What happens is probably

```
i++; // from threadNew, i is now 1
i++; // from incrementer, i is now 2
System.out.println("i count=" + i); // from threadNew outputs 2
System.out.println("increment count="+i); //from incrementer outputs 2
```

Your example does not make much sense though. Synchronize on the same object. Don't create two instances as suggested by @Matt Ball

Comment: I want to execute the threads one after one as the execution order is very incorrect. I still know that, order of execution depends on JVM

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace synchronized (this) with...

```
synchronized (StaticThreadTest.class) {
 ...
}
```

Not very efficient, but whatever...

Comment: Thanks. Tried it too.